# Example of module homomorphism from torsion to free

Tags: ring-theory, modules

Can someone give an example of an R module homorphism from a torsion mkdule N to free module M where R is commutative with unity with the homomorphism different from the zero one
I know if we dont have zero divisors then the only possibility is the zero homomorphism but  if the ring has zero divisors can someone give an example of non truvial homomorphism?
Thanks all helpers

Comment: What is your definition of "torsion module" over a ring with zero divisors?  Just that every element is annihilated by some nonzero element of the ring?

Comment: For a commutative ring, you define an element to be a torsion-element iff its annihilator contains at least one non-zero-divisor. In particular any module over a finite ring is torsion free, since all elements in a finite ring are either units (hence not contained in an annihilator) or zero-divisors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the embedding $2R\times\{0\}\to R\times\mathbb{Z}$, where $R=\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: $2R$ is a torsion-free $R$-module, since the annihilator of $2,4 \in 2R$ consist of zero-divisors only.

Comment: @MooS Just add something that's not a zero-divisor

Comment: Indeed, now it works.

Comment: Then what is the example?